# Footnotes and atbegshi header

Tags: footnotes, parallel, atbegshi, eledpar

I have done combination of eledpar and parcolumns packages 4 parallel texts on 2 pages.
Using Atbegshi package adding page headers.
Everything works fine, but when I add footnote page headers are lost.
Here is a code.. If you comment footnotes everything works fine.

```
        \documentclass[10pt]{memoir}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage{eledmac}
        \usepackage{eledpar}
         \usepackage{parcolumns}
        \usepackage{xcolor}
         \usepackage{atbegshi}
         \usepackage{lipsum}
        \foottwocolX{A}
        \let\footnote\footnoteA
        \parindent 0pt

         \newcommand{\pcheader}{\hspace*{0.2\textwidth}\textbf{A}{\hspace*{0.5\textwidth}\textbf{B}}\vspace*{1ex}\hrule}
         \newcommand{\kpcheader}{\hspace*{0.2\textwidth}\textbf{C}{\hspace*{0.5\textwidth}\textbf{D}}\vspace*{1ex}\hrule}

         \AtBeginShipout{%
        \checkoddpage
        \ifoddpage
         \pcheader
        \else
        \kpcheader
        \fi
        }%


        \begin{document}


         \sloppy
        \begin{pages}

        \begin{Leftside}
         \beginnumbering
        \pstart
        \begin{parcolumns}[nofirstindent,rulebetween=true]{2}   \colchunk[1]{

                \section*{LL1}\mbox{}
                {\color{red} testing color bug}

            \lipsum[3]
            test\footnote{footnote 1}
            \lipsum[3]
            }
            \colchunk[2]{

            \section*{LR1}\mbox{}
            \lipsum[3]
            test\footnote{footnote 2}
            \lipsum[3]
            }
            \colplacechunks
        \end{parcolumns}
        \begin{parcolumns}[nofirstindent,rulebetween=true]{2}   \colchunk[1]{

                \section*{LL2}\mbox{}


            }
            \colchunk[2]{

                \section*{LR2}\mbox{}

            }
            \colplacechunks
        \end{parcolumns}

        \pend
        \endnumbering% <
        \end{Leftside}
        \begin{Rightside}

        \beginnumbering
        \pstart 
        \begin{parcolumns}[rulebetween=true]{2} 
            \colchunk[1]{

        \section*{RL1}\mbox{}
            }
                \colchunk[2]{

                \section*{RR1}\mbox{}

                }
                \colplacechunks
                    \colchunk[1]{
                            {\color{red} testing color bug}
                    }
            \colchunk[2]{
            \mbox{}
            }
                \colplacechunks

                \colchunk[1]{

            \lipsum[1-2]
            test\footnote{footnote 3}
            \lipsum[1-2]
                }
                \colchunk[2]{
                    \lipsum[3]
                    test\footnote{footnote 4}
                    \lipsum[3]
                }
            \colplacechunks

        \end{parcolumns}
        \pend
        \endnumbering% <--

        \end{Rightside}
        \Pages
        \end{pages}

        \AtBeginShipout\AtBeginShipoutDiscard
        \end{document}
```

Comment: You haven't got any answer yet. I'm guessing that's because your code is too long and contains irrelevant stuff, and nobody likes to plough through pages and pages of code to find out where the problem lies. You need to condense your code to the minimum required for compiling *and* explaining the problem; see [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228),

Comment: Using eledmaqcs Left/Right pages mechanism to have parallel texts on pages. For those pages I plugged on each page parallel columns for parcolumns package. So effect I have is: Left side pages I have parallel texts in 2 columns using parcolumns. Same for Right side pages. Atbegshi (macros pcheader and kpcheader) adds "A,B,C,D" on every page for parallel texts. footnote macro adds footnotes (footnoteA comes from eledpar). Just copy paste above code, comment footnotes and you see what you get. Then put footnote commands back and you can see problem. this is MWE.Sorry...comment line with "cmgt"

Comment: @LevanShoshiashvili What exactly are you trying to do? Would you like to have 4 parallel columns on two pages, eg. on pages 2 and 3? Has the content of each column to be indpendent from the content of any other column? Please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: 4 columns are working. all 4 column texts are different. Each column has a header(Using Atbegshi package) (A,B)(left pages) and (C,D)(right pages). Without footnotes everything works fine. When I use footnote those headers are lost on page just after footnote page. It seems current page/or pagechange is not calculated. See outputs here [example outputs][1]
  [1]: http://lshoshia.science.tsu.ge/paralleltext/

Comment: If I use just \footnote everything works...eledmacs footnoteA footnoteB command break 'the headers'

Comment: It seems parcolumns problem . can not use \footnoteA command...working for replacement any suggestions?

Comment: Yes it seems problem is too complex. I decided following: 1. Instead of atbegshi or everypage use memoir pagestyles. 2. For 4 parallel texts use package parallel and hanging. With parallel combination with eledpar i can use eledpar footnotes.